# Connect minecraft with discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js, minecraft

Any way to connect discord.js with minecraft server, i wanna type in discord my nickname in channel #reward
and got in minecraft 10 diamonds on my nickname,

i trying to use rest but idk how to implement miencraft + discord.js

someone has idea?

Comment: If you want to integrate Minecraft with Discord, you can use plugins made for your Minecraft server installation. If you really do want to code your own though, I would recommend that you read into plugin development for Minecraft servers using another language named Java, then try integrating that into your bot.

Answer (score 0):

Discord.js does not include any features for Minecraft, however, you could use a webhook plugin (If using spigot/paper/bukkit...) or find an online webhook. You could even set up a hidden discord channel where the bot can read the webhooks and announce them in its own way.
You may be able to link RCon with your discord bot to give you diamond if you did indeed type your nickname in #reward, however, there is no official way to do this (to my knowledge)

Comment: someone tell me they use rest api for that like discord -> rest api website -> minecraft but i dont know how to connect this         //sry for eng btw

Comment: You may be able to develop your own plugin to do this (Like ClientCrash said), however, you'd need a way for the plugin and discord bot to communicate (The discord java api uses ReST, so perhaps you could ask your friend for help?). To be honest, I would probably give up at this point, using the commands.yml file and creating an alias for giving a player diamonds. Anyway, if you are looking for an easy option... I don't think mixing js and java is a good idea. Despite their names, they are different, by a lot. I don't use js or java, so... can't really contribute anymore, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can user the [discord java api](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/) to create the bot inside a plugin or you can use [mineflayer](https://github.com/PrismarineJS/mineflayer) and discord.js to create a minecraft bot and a discord bot and let them communicate using websockets.

Answer (score 0):

If your bot is able to interact with the commandline, you can use RCon.
MCRcon is a cross-platform rcon client which is run via the commandline.
There may also be a js library for RCon.

Using RCon:
Make sure it is able to access the #reward channel. You need to make it so it can see the messages and find usernames.
You need to execute the following command (mcrcon):

`mcrcon -H <hostname> -P <RCon Port> -s (Prevents Feedback) -p <RCon Password> "give <username> diamond"`

For MCRCon: https://sourceforge.net/projects/mcrcon/

*Note: MCRCon is available for both Windows and Linux*

Answer (score 0):

You can use a discord java api (ex. [JDA](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA)) to make a bot, which is gonna take user parameter and gonna process this through [rcon](https://wiki.vg/RCON)

Answer (score 0):

If the other answers don't help, the easiest way to connect Minecraft and Discord is thru a Minecraft Plugin and Addon that lets you control your bot. The plugin is called **Skript** and the addon is called **Vixio**. There is a full tutorial on how to set it up [here](https://youtu.be/AXGETouUzoo)
I hope it works for you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're hosting your minecraft server on a pterodactyl server then you can just send a request to their api to post a command on the prompt.