# Send a command to a separate command prompt window from node.js process

Tags: node.js, discord.js, command-prompt, minecraft

I have a bot that runs on a VM with a private Minecraft server. What I am trying to do (and have not found anything online about) is send a command to the Minecraft server process (the server is the paper software) from a Node.JS process (Discord.JS bot) already running. Like say in a DM someone sends a command (/kill littlebitsman) and it would send it to the console, and in-game it would run /kill as the console, and the returned message is sent to the author of the message If possible, I would like it so that chat messages are relayed to a specific channel in a guild.

I looked this up online and found nothing, so I have no idea how or if this would work.

Comment: Minecraft can use rcon for admin tasks, if you enable it, you can communicate with your minecraft server over the rcon protocol from your discord bot.

Comment: how could you use RCON for that? Does it use HTTP POST, or something like that?

Comment: rcon is a protocol based ontop of tcp/ip: https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Source_RCON_Protocol. There a a bunch full of npm modules you can use: https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=rcon Once a rcon connection is established, you can send any cli command (like /kill) via the rcon session to your minecraft server.

Comment: Maybe you can find answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58006226/connect-minecraft-with-discord-js)